# Start external program with arguments (in Visual Studio - Debug properties)

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to run program with parameters, like on screenshot (Specifically, I've tried to run CMD with some params):

[image]

It gives me an error while I am trying to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be stemming from the second path in your argument. Try wrapping whatever the `C:\Program Fi` (it's cut off in the screenshot) path is in quotes.

```
C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe start /m "" "C:\Program Files(x86)\Path\To\Directory"
```

Answer (score 3):

You should specify parameters in the **Command line arguments** box:

[image]

Comment: i wanted CMD to start other window, and that doesn't work for me  :(

Comment: Could anyone show how the .csproj.user file looks like with this?

Comment: @DanielMöller <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <StartAction>Program</StartAction>
    <StartProgram>notepad.exe</StartProgram>
    <StartArguments>1.txt</StartArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Comment: The Command line arguments field applies to the Visual Studio program, not the one specified in the "Start external program." As far as I can tell, it is impossible to add command line arguments to the "Start external program" .exe. Visual Studio pops up a warning that says "This is not a valid .exe file."